# Why don't I see w3wp in the SharpDevelop debugger's "attach to process" list?

Tags: asp.net, debugging, sharpdevelop

If you need a "standalone" CLR debugger (such as .NET 2 offered), SharpDevelop is a good alternative to VS (if you're into that kind of thing).

However, when trying to debug a running ASP.NET application, I did not see `w3wp` listed in "Attach to Process".  Why not?

In the spirit of ["Q&A-style" sharing](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/), I'm posting this item I've already figured out.  I found that there were two somewhat non-obvious requirements.

Comment: SharpDevelop is 32 bit debugging only, so if you are on 64 bit Windows, w3wp might be 64 bit and SD cannot debug it. Meanwhile, you should try to run SharpDevelop as admin and try again, as admin rights are also necessary.

Comment: @LexLi, post that as an answer and I'll accept it.  You hit both points.  Specifically, you can make the WP show up by setting "Enable 32-bit Applications" for that app pool in IIS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SharpDevelop is 32 bit debugging only, so if you are on 64 bit Windows, w3wp might be 64 bit and SD cannot debug it. Simply set IIS application pool to 32 bit and you only get 32 bit w3wp.

Meanwhile, you should try to run SharpDevelop as admin and try again, as admin rights are also necessary.

Comment: +1 for helping me *again* when I found this question myself a year later!

Comment: This is getting ridiculous.  Well, at least I only need the debugger once a year!

Comment: @harpo Microsoft has stood up and provided VS Community Edition. You can see SharpDevelop has stopped active development.